# Set assets path for `exports` property in package.json

Tags: angular, webpack

I noticed that since Angular 13 Webpack started to add `exports` property to the package.json. And it breaks my library package. That is because there are SCSS and asset files in the library and those are consumed by `@import` statement by the apps. The compiler can't resolve SCSS and assets. I managed to find the correct path pattern for SCSS files:

```
    "./scss/*": {
      "sass": "./scss/*.scss"
    },
```

But when I try to do something similar with `assets` I fail. Here are some of the combinations I tried:

```
"./assets/*": "./**/*",
---
"./assets/*": {
  "asset": "./*"
},
---
"./assets/*": {
   "asset": ["./assets/fonts/materialicons/*"]
},
```

The only combination which works for me is when I specify the *full* path to a particular asset. So this works:

```
   "./assets/*": "./assets/fonts/materialicons/MaterialIcons-Outlined.woff2",
```

The error is as follows:

```
./apps/contacts-app/src/styles.scss.webpack[javascript/auto]!=!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[0].oneOf[0].use[2]!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[1].use[0]!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[5].rules[1].use[1]!./apps/contacts-app/src/styles.scss - Error: Module Error (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
path_to_dir/repo_name/apps/contacts-app/src/styles.scss:362:13: Package path ./assets/fonts/materialicons/MaterialIcons-Outlined.woff2 is not exported from package path_to_dir/repo_name/node_modules/@namespace/my-lib (see exports field in path_to_dir/repo_name/node_modules/@namespace/my-lib/package.json)
```

Of corse I can specify explicitly every asset file in the the assets path, but I got more than 500 files. And that doesn't look right.
Does anyone know what is the proper way *specifying all asset files in a particular directory recursively*? Thanks you!

Comment: @Drenai, I tried. But it just copied the resources into the lib dist directory. It doesn’t add those assets into ‘exports’ in the generated library package.json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer. The issue occurred because the assets were referred from inside the library using the *package name* instead of the relative path.
Let's say here is a package structure:

```
@namespace/my-lib
|-> scss/src/main.scss
|-> assets/fonts/materialicons/MaterialIcons-Outlined.woff2
```

Then here is how the font was referred to from main.scss:

```
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Material Icons Outlined";
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("~@namespace/my-lib/assets/fonts/materialicons/MaterialIcons-Outlined.woff2") format("woff2")    
}
```

and here is how it should be referred:

```
@font-face {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: "Material Icons Outlined";
  font-style: normal;
  src: url("../../assets/fonts/materialicons/MaterialIcons-Outlined.woff2") format("woff2")    
}
```

With this fix there is no need to specify `assets` in the `exports` property of the libs's package.json at all.